# Crystal Reports Parameters - One List rather than pages

Tags: crystal-reports

All,

My first ever post - here goes!

I am using a Dynamic Parameter to filter a report based on Purchase Order Number.

I have created the Parameter, but only so many results are on the list, then you have to change to page 2 and start looking through again, is there anyway to get all values on a single list.

I have am awaiting my IT Department to do the Registry edit to increase the search size, as I have well over 1,000 records.

Finally, I assume the user couldn't search for a relevant value in the list?

I am using Crystal Reports 2011 64 Bit Version

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have the ability to build apps using C#, Visual Basic or some other programming language that can easily interface with a Crystal Report?  When I had this problem, I found the better solution for my needs was to implement the list outside of the report using a custom application, then pass the selected value to the report as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your question, unfortunately not, we use PBI Dataflows and Crystal as the methods of reporting, I can easily get around the issue in PBI, but ideally need the Crystal Report to do the same within the application its going to be loaded into